# Custom Button renderer and unexpected properties change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to create a Button with custom color text when disabled. For this point i successfully did the job with a custom renderer.
But an unexpected side effect as came. Some button style are disapplying when passing on this specific state.

[image]

As you can see on the image above the button icon position is different and the cornerRadius property isn't applied anymore.

In the enable state with the custom button renderer i recover the cornerRadius property (actually i can resolve this problem setting each time the radius in the renderer, so isn't really a problem). The icon remain at the top and doesn't respect the ContentLayout margin property. The renderer i expect is the left button who is did with normal button component.

[image]

Here is the declaration of my control (i put the left button too to demonstrate the settings are the same:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50,0,0">
                    <Button Text="Disponibilités de l'élève" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="10" ContentLayout="Top,25" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonWidth}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding OpenMapCommand}">
                        <Button.ImageSource>
                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Color="White" Glyph="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarDays}"/>
                        </Button.ImageSource>
                    </Button>

                    <!--<Button Text="Poser une option" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="White" BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="10" ContentLayout="Top,25" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonWidth}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding SubmitOptionCommand}">
                        <Button.ImageSource>
                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Color="White" Glyph="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarPlus}"/>
                        </Button.ImageSource>
                    </Button>-->
                    <controls:DisableExtentButton Text="Poser une option" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" DisabledBackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="White" DisabledTextColor="Green" BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="10" ContentLayout="Top,25" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonWidth}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding SubmitOptionCommand}">
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding OptionTaken}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="ImageSource">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Color="Green" Glyph="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarCheck}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                        <Button.ImageSource>
                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Color="White" Glyph="{x:Static fa:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarPlus}"/>
                        </Button.ImageSource>
                    </controls:DisableExtentButton>
                </StackLayout>
```

Here is the declaration of my custom Control:

```
public class DisableExtentButton : Button 
{ 
    public Color DisabledTextColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(DisabledTextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisabledTextColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color DisabledBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(DisabledBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisabledBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty DisabledTextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DisabledTextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DisableExtentButton), Color.Gray);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DisabledBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DisabledBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DisableExtentButton), Color.DarkGray);
}
```

The android renderer:

```
public class DisableExtentButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public DisableExtentButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        if (Control != null)
            SetColors();
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Button.IsEnabled))
            SetColors();
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    private void SetColors()
    {
        var element = (DisableExtentButton)this.Element;
        Control.SetTextColor(Element.IsEnabled ? Element.TextColor.ToAndroid() : element.DisabledTextColor.ToAndroid());
        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Element.IsEnabled ? Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid() : element.DisabledBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
    }
}
```

I didn't successfully found why the ContentLayout property isn't applied correctly anymore and more for informational purpose why the corner radius is reseted when passing into OnElementPropertyChanged. If i redo the button without custom renderer it work as expected like the left button.

Comment: If all you need to do is change the color based on IsEnabled, i think the [Visual State Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager) is the much easier way to go.

Comment: Well i tried it before but with a DataTrigger changing the isEnabled property value and it didn't work doing the same with changing the isEnabled binding on the vm work pretty well thanks for the answer !

Comment: If you want to change the TextColor and the BackgroundColor based on IsEnabled, you don't have to use the Custom Renderer. You can set the value of then in the trigger. Such as `<Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>`